# Why some pods needs to be imported in every file where I want to use it,some just needs to be import once?

Tags: swift, cocoapods

When I use cocoapods,I find Snapkit only needs to be imported once, and it can be used in other files. But SwiftyJSON needs to be imported in every file where I want to use it. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depend upon access specifier used in Particular library. 
Variable used in Particular library. Because variable may cause conflict with Library variables.

If required data of library are in public part then you can import framework at once in AppDelegate.swift.